# Why is hypothetical example code off-topic for Code Review?

Tags: discussion, faq, scope, asking-questions, example-code

As stated in the [Help Center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), one of the criteria for a question to be on topic is:

> - **Is it actual code from a project** rather than pseudo-code or hypothetical code?
>   Details matter! In order to give good advice, we need to see real, concrete code, and understand the context in which the code is used. Generic code (such as code containing placeholders like `foo`, `MyClass`, or `doSomething()`) leaves too much to the imagination.

What is the rationale for that rule?

Comment: Related: [Is pseudo-code alright when asking about performance?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/594)

Answer (score 29):

Hypothetical code makes poor Code Review questions, which produce poor answers.

For example, here is a [code excerpt that made a poor Code Review question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/46231/5):

> ```
> bool f(const string& key, const string& value)
> {
>     // some codes for input check
>     exec_cmd("cmd %s %s", key.c_str(), value.c_str());
>     // some codes for making return value
> }
>
> bool f(const string& key, unsigned long value)
> {
>     // some codes for input check
>     exec_cmd("cmd %s %lu", key.c_str(), value);
>     // some codes for making return value
> }
> ```

Why is this question problematic?  It has been **stripped of all context,** making it hard to give concrete advice.  Some of the warning signs are:

- Generic function name `f()`.  The question is based on a true story — in other words, it's fictitious, hypothetical code.
- Probable generic string `"cmd"`.
- Placeholder comments (with insufficient detail to mentally reconstruct the code that goes there).
- The function should return a `bool`, but we don't know what that `bool` represents.
- We can speculate what `exec_cmd()` does, and by extension, what `f()` does, but we're not really sure.

Compare what happens when the author [fills in enough details](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/46231/7) to resolve three of the five deficiencies:

> ```
> bool set(const string& key, const string& value)
> {
>     // some codes for input check
>     redisCommand("SET %s %s", key.c_str(), value.c_str());
>     // some codes for making return value
> }
>
> bool set(const string& key, unsigned long value)
> {
>     // some codes for input check
>     redisCommand("SET %s %lu", key.c_str(), value);
>     // some codes for making return value
> }
> ```

Now, we can see exactly what the code is supposed to do, and can give better advice.  For example, previously we could only [speculate](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/46236/1) that there was a security hole in the code.  Now that we know that it is trying to set a value in a redis database, the mitigation advice would be completely different.

We don't normally allow code in questions to be edited like that, since it invalidates existing answers.  However, in this case, the original question was so poor that allowing the revision was a less bad option.  Ideally, the original question should have been closed as "not real code" instead of being reviewed, to avoid such a mess.

Answer (score 18):

Hypothetical code is difficult or impossible to review because it is a moving, shape-shifting target.  For example, @elibyy asked:

> ### https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/60562/9357
>
> for example i'm deleting file if it exist
>
> ```
> if(file_exists('path/to/file')){
>     unlink('path/to/file');
> }
> ```

An answer was given:

> You could just call
>
> ```
> @unlink('path/to/file');
> ```

… to which the original author [responded](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60562/should-i-contain-use-a-variable-to-avoid-mentioning-a-filename-twice#comment109696_60565):

> <sub>however my question is in the abstract perspective, the delete file is example</sub>

When code is hypothetical, it can mean whatever the author wants it to mean, and we can't read the author's mind.  When `unlink()` doesn't actually mean `unlink()`, "reviewing" code is a waste of time for everybody.

Answer (score 9):

In [Keeping track of byte count in a binary protocol handler](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/47396/9357), we had an example of a question that [originally contained stub code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/47396/2) that did not accomplish very much.  After being put on hold, the author [added more code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/47396/3).  It then became apparent that there were deeper problems that needed to be addressed.

Answer (score -12):

> A hammer can be used as a tool and as a weapon . Is that a reason to
>   prohibit the use of a hammer?

Problem is that sometimes original code have too much irrelevant code. So if you add whole code than reader will have problem to read everything, plus you will get comments that are not relevant to your question. I usually need help with general problem, when I implement something but I am quite sure that can be done better. I don't care about better naming, or better some other not relevant thing that will be done later or not, because is not important for me. So hypothetical code is good to keep focus on general point of question, and to get straight answer.
Ofcours there is risk with hypothetical code if is not good enough, but that is problem in person that use hypothetical code in wrong way. It is not problem in hypothetical code.

Comment: You not liking advice on better naming and such isn't a good reason for allowing hypothetical code.

Comment: Related: [Can we ask reviewers to not focus on something?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1884/can-we-ask-reviewers-to-not-focus-on-something)

Comment: @Jamal Not it is not. But hypothetical code is very useful when your orginal code is too complicated. So you can keep focus on point using hypothetical code. I many cases my questions would be much better and cleaner with hypothetical code.

Comment: Then a hypothetical variation can be posted on Stack Overflow or Programmers.

Comment: @Jamal: There you will get short answer wih some good advice (or not). But I want code review focused on point. Anwer I get on codereview are are much helpful to me. Problem is that sometimes it does not make sanse to copy-paste my orginal code, its to complicated, and to hard for reading for somone that is not familiar with my project.

Comment: Then perhaps Code Review doesn't always suite your needs, and that's not a bad thing. Plus, if unfamiliarity with someone else's code was a problem, then this site probably wouldn't even be around today. Learning to understanding someone else's code *is* the point.

Comment: @merso0027 I do tend to agree with you.  If I can identify the specific PATTERN of code that gives problems, then I can eliminate TENS or even HUNDREDS OF LINES of code completely unrelated to the problem, yet still retain a perfectly functional demonstration of the problem, the understanding of which would allow me to correct the actual problem, and convey to others both the pitfall and the correction of an anti-pattern.  Alas, apparently such is not the mindset of CR.