# Info request: "Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received"

Tags: support, specific-question

I have [7 questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/6749/gibbok?tab=questions) with several positive up-votes and 2 deleted by myself. Today I received this message when trying to ask a question:

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more....

I read on the link provided, which stated:

> ...but users are only banned if they have a significant number of heavily down-voted, zero-voted, or deleted posts

Regarding my case:

- Could you please evaluate my case and let me know why I have received this warning message?
- Are misspelling or errors somehow counted?

Answer (score 7):

Your two most recent questions were closed as off-topic.  Specifically, they were judged to be generic/hypothetical code rather than real code.

---

In [Best practicing for passing an object as parameters to a function](//codereview.stackexchange.com/q/78984)…

```
} else if (options.canGetDefault && options.type === 'xxx') {
    if (item.xxx.is_default === true) {
        result = item;
    }
}
```

… the likely trigger were the `xxx` placeholders.  What do you mean by them?  For that matter, `_data` is vague too, and we don't really know the context in which you would call `_find(options)`.

---

In [Implementing Command Pattern - How to make more readable if else statements for commands?](//codereview.stackexchange.com/q/79691)…

```
var cmdP = {
       _unexecuted: [],
      _executed: [],
        execute: function (cmd) {

            this._unexecuted.length = 0; // common
//---------------------------------- check type
            if (cmd.declaredClass === 'a') {
                alert('logic change cmd for type a');
            } else if (cmd.declaredClass === 'b') {
                alert('logic change cmd for type b');
            }
//----------------------------------
            cmd.execute(); // common
            this._executed.push(cmd); // common

    }
    }
      var cmd = {
        declaredClass: 'b',
         execute:function(){
           alert('cmd executed')
         }
      };
      cmdP.execute(cmd);
```

… "execute some operations on a passed object" is a generic problem, and `'a'` and `'b'` are hypothetical names.  In addition, the `alert()` calls are placeholders.

---

Please read [Why is hypothetical example code off-topic for Code Review?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1709/9357) to understand why these decontextualized questions are problematic.  You may think that you are being helpful by stripping out irrelevant detail.  However, these modifications make it impossible to write a good review.  We can't tell which parts of your code are literal and which parts are hypothetical.  There is also a chance that you've stripped out very relevant information that would have allowed us to give you better advice.

For these reasons, Code Review deals only in concrete code.  Please give us the straight, unadulterated version of your code so that we can review it properly.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Now I understand.

Comment: Addendum to my answer: titles should reflect the task performed by the code, [not how you want to transform it](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2454/9357). If you can't summarize the purpose of the code in the title, there's a good chance that the question is hypothetical.