# Would Code Review be a good site to post formatting questions?

Tags: discussion, site-policy

I've been thinking recently that Code Review might encapsulate Code Presentation style, such as:

- Helpful comments and documentation.
- Indentation/bracketing style.
- Overall code structure.

Of course, I realise that this can be downright subjective. For instance, there's always this little thing that people disagree on:

```
Something {
    thing;
    other;
}
```

Or:

```
Something
{
    thing;
    other;
}
```

Or even

```
Something
{ thing
; other
;}
```

These issues aside, would it be acceptable to post a question such as "How can I make this code look tidier?" on Code Review? If so, with what restrictions, and if not, why?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can. With some gotchas:

**Do not post example code**

This is a big subject that is covered well in our meta post about [Why is hypothetical code off-topic for Code Review?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1709/why-is-hypothetical-example-code-off-topic-for-code-review)

**Avoid A vs. B questions**

Decide on the formatting you like the most first, then ask for feedback about it.

Posting two versions of your code may get closed as "primarily opinion-based". There are some things which are just... holy wars... that programmers never agree about (for example spaces vs. tabs and Egyptian-style vs C#-style braces)

Comment: Pfft. Everyone knows you just let the IDE turn tabs into spaces. Holy war ended. Braces on the other hand... Well now...

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that the question is about a programming language that has no official style guide, if a question is purely about whitespace, I would likely move to close it as Primarily Opinion Based.  I would view such a question as a skirmish in the never-ending Brace Wars.  Such discussions are rarely conclusive or productive.

If phrased in a sufficiently open-ended way, though, the question could work.  The following factors could swing the decision in your favour:

- Instead of asking point-blank about formatting choices A, B, or C (what we call a [comparative-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative-review)), just post one version of it and mention your concern about the problematic lines.
- Include sufficient surrounding code and background information about what the code aims to achieve, so that reviewers have latitude to rewrite the smelly code altogether.

Answer (score 5):

You can already do this: in this site, you can say something like this:

> How can I make my code look neater?

*Or something along those lines.*

Answer (score 2):

If you were writing something in Python and you wanted to know if you were following code standards, you would say something like *"is my code Pythonic enough"* or something to that effect.

other terms are

- DRY -> Don't Repeat Yourself
- Clean
- Neat
- Idiomatic

If you hang around long enough you will pick up some nice terms for talking about writing code that explains itself and is easy to read.